# Orientation for compact manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, orientation

[Page 253, -8 to -4 line](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) Hatcher defines orientation for compact manifolds with boundary.

> A compact manifold is $R$_orientable if $M-\partial M$ is $R$-orientable.
>
> If $\partial M \times [0,1)$ is a collar nhood of $\partial M$ in $M$, then $H_i(M,\partial M;R)$ is naturally isomorphic to $H_i(M-\partial M, \partial M \times (0,\varepsilon);R)$

I do not see how we have this isomoprhism.

> Lemma 3.27 (page 236) gives a relative fundamental class $[M]$ in $H_n(M, \partial M;R)$ restricting to a given orientation at each point of $M - \partial M$.

What is a "relative fundamental class" and how does this conclusion follow? I am lost with the two described steps.

Comment: $\partial M$ is a subset of $\partial M\times [0,\epsilon)$ which is open in $M$. So you can apply excision to get
$H(M,\partial M\times [0,\epsilon))\simeq H(M-\partial M,\partial M\times (0,\epsilon))$. Finally $H(M,\partial M\times [0,\epsilon))\simeq H(M,\partial M)$ via long exact sequence of homologies. Note that $\partial M\times [0,\epsilon)$ deformation retracts onto $\partial M$ (at least when $M$ is compact and $\epsilon$ small enough) and so $H(\partial M\times [0,\epsilon), \partial M)=0$.

Comment: I'm not sure about the other question though.

Comment: @freakish, thanks I actually found an exact question to my question, I will delete this post - do you mind having a look at my post on Poincare's proof?